# Jquery plugin - Pick times during week

Tags: jquery, datetime

Want to show a Monday - Friday 24 hour week time selector.  I basically need people to be able to select a shift that they work.

It's generic, not actual dates on a calendar, just Monday - Friday and what hours each day.

Can't seem to find anything like this - Any ideas?

Comment: Seriously - That's helpful - I tried google and couldn't find a plugin exactly meeting my needs and figured someone here might have run across something.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Timepicker to jQuery UI Datepicker. See out [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) example

Comment: Thanks, I saw that one but that's with a calendar, which would confuse people - Just want generic Monday-Friday.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jquery plugin like Week Calendar (30th in http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-calendar-plugins/ )

Comment: I saw that and that's close, the only thing it doesn't let me do is select multiple days at once.  Like if they want to select 8-5 Monday to Friday, they would have to do it for each day as opposed to highlighting it across the board.  I guess something like this just doesn't exist.